# How to fix SQL Trigger

Tags: sql, triggers

How to fix it?

```
CREATE TRIGGER tb_mhs2_hapus AFTER DELETE 
ON tb_mhs2 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO tb_mhs2_hapus (nama, no, alamat, org_tua, timeee) VALUES (old.nama, old.no, old.alamat, old.org_tua, SYSDATE());
END;
```

im confused where im wrong? "You have an error in your SQL syntax;"

Answer (score 0):

First of all why your trigger name is same as table name? `tb_mhs2_hapus`

So your code should be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_tb_mhs2_hapus 
AFTER DELETE ON tb_mhs2 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO tb_mhs2_hapus (nama, no, alamat, org_tua, timeee) 
  VALUES (old.nama, old.no, old.alamat, old.org_tua, SYSDATE());
END;
```

Comment: still wrong mister CREATE TRIGGER OR REPLACE TRG_tb_mhs2_hapus 
AFTER DELETE ON tb_mhs2 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO tb_mhs2_hapus (nama, no, alamat, org_tua, timeee) 
  VALUES (:old.nama, :old.no, :old.alamat, :old.org_tua, SYSDATE)
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'OR REPLACE TRG_tb_mhs2_hapus
AFTER DELETE ON tb_mhs2
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
...' at line 1